# Cómo leer valores de hora correctamente en una hoja de cálculo de Google

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

## Panorama

La celda `A1` tiene el valor `01:00` (una hora). Al usar una función como la siguiente:

```
function prueba() {
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hoja = libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 1");
  var datos = hoja.getDataRange().getValues();
  var valor = datos[0][0];
  Logger.log(valor.getHours());
  Logger.log(valor.getMinutes());
}
```

Se registran los valores

```
1.0  
36.0
```

Lo esperado es que los valores registrados fueran:

```
1.0  
0.0
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi código lea los valores esperados?

## Comentarios

Esta es una "pregunta real" para la cual encontré la respuesta en [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com). Véase la referencia.

No se tradujo la pregunta, pero podría decir que está basada en la referencia.

## Referencias

- [How to read the correct time values from Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17715841/1595451)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Panorama

La hoja de cálculo y Javascript manejan de forma diferente las fechas por lo que es necesario introducir una líneas de código adicionales. Se presenta una función principal y dos complementarias para obtener segundos, minutos u horas a partir de una fecha.

## Código

Modificaciones a la función presentada en la pregunta:

```
function prueba() {
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hoja = libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 1");
  /* Las siguientes líneas se puede retirar
    var datos = hoja.getDataRange().getValues();
    var valor = datos[1][1];
    Logger.log(valor.getHours());
    Logger.log(valor.getMinutes());
  */
  // Agregar las siguientes líneas
  var h = Math.floor(getValueAsHours(hoja.getRange(2,2)));
  var m = Math.floor(getValueAsMinutes(hoja.getRange(2,2))) - h*60;
  Logger.log(h);
  Logger.log(m);
}
```

De la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17727300/1595451) de [Eric Koleda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702875/eric-koleda) del 2013-07-22 14:20:54Z se tomaron las siguientes funciones auxiliares:

```
function getValueAsSeconds(range) {
  var value = range.getValue();

  // Tomar el valor de fecha en la zona horaria de la hoja de cálculo.
  var spreadsheetTimezone = range.getSheet().getParent()
      .getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(value, spreadsheetTimezone, 
      'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss');
  var date = new Date(dateString);

  // Inicializar la fecha del epoch.
  var epoch = new Date('Dec 30, 1899 00:00:00');

  // Calcular el número de milisegundos entre el epoch y el valor
  var diff = date.getTime() - epoch.getTime();

  // Convertir los milisegundos a segundos y devolver el resultado.
  return Math.round(diff / 1000);
}

function getValueAsMinutes(range) {
  return getValueAsSeconds(range) / 60;
}

function getValueAsHours(range) {
  return getValueAsMinutes(range) / 60;
}
```

Ejemplo de uso para registrar las horas de la celda `A1`.

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1');
Logger.log(getValueAsHours(range));
```

## Explicación

De la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17716798/1595451) de [Sergei insas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1368381/serge-insas) del 2013-07-18 15:36:28Z

Las hojas de cálculo usan como fecha de referencia `12/30/1899` mientras que Javascript usa `01/01/1970`, esto significa que hay 25,568 días de diferencia entre ambas referencias. Esto asumiendo que se usa la misma zona horaria en ambos sistemas. Cuando se convierte un valor de fecha en una hoja de cálculo a objeto de fecha de Javascript el motor GAF automáticamente agrega la diferencia para mantener la consistencia entre ambas fechas.

En este caso no se desea saber la fecha real de algo, en su lugar se desea un valor absoluto de horas, por ejemplo, una duración, así que es necesario quitar el desfasamiento de 25,568 días. Esto es realiza usando el método `getTime()` el cual da como resultado milisegundos contados desde la fecha de referencia de Javascript, la única cosa que sabes es el valor en milisegundos de la fecha de la hoja de cálculo de referencia y restar este valor de la objeto de fecha actual. Luego un poco de matemáticas para obtener horas en lugar milisegundos y terminamos.

## Comentarios

El Issue 402: Get literal string from a spreadsheet range se mencionó en la respuesta de Eric, pero esta fue [marcado como arreglado](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=402#c26) hace 4 días con la observación de que la documentación está por ser publicada. Se resolvió agregando range.getDisplayValue y range.getDisplayValues, sin embargo, esto podría no ser útil en el caso de que no se desee modificar el formato en el que se muestra un dato del tipo fecha.

En relación al código, se tradujeron los comentarios incluidos en el mismo, pero las nombres de la variables se dejaron tal cual. Se introdujo un salto de línea en un de las líneas que estaba demasiado larga para evitar que se muestre la barra de desplazamiento horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

Desde el punto de vista de un principiante, o "rápido y sucio", quizás la solución más sencilla es que en lugar de usar métodos como `getValue` / `getValues` se use `getDisplayValue` / `getDisplayValues` para trabajar con objetos tipo String en lugar de objetos tipo Date.

## Conceptos básicos

Internamente las hojas de cálculo de Google y JavaScript usan números seriales para manejar fechas y horas, esto es, usan un "EPOCH", como punto de referencia o cero y a partir del cual se suman unidades de tiempo para determinar la fecha-hora.

### Unidad de tiempo

- En las hojas de cálculo de Google la unidad de tiempo es un día
- En JavaScript es un milisegundo.

### EPOCH

- En la hoja de cálculo de Google el EPOCH es 30 de diciembre de 1899 00:00:00. No usa zona horaria
- En JavaScript el EPOCH es 1 de enero de 1970, 00:00:00 UTC

### Conversión

Cuando Google Apps Script lee un valor de hora, también considera la zona horaria de la hoja de cálculo y la zona horaria del proyecto de Apps Script, las cuáles no siempre son iguales, y esto podría agregar unos minutos y segundos en ciertos casos, por ejemplo

- Si en la hoja de cálculo de Google configurada con zona horaria del Centro de México se tiene `0:00:00`, el objeto Date mostrará `Sat Dec 30 1899 00:36:36 GMT-0600 (CST)`

### Ejemplo

#### Modificación del código de la pregunta

```
function prueba() {
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hoja = libro.getSheetByName("Hoja 1");
  var datos = hoja.getDataRange().getValues();
  var valor = datos[0][0].match(/\d\d/g);
  Logger.log(valor[0]); // Hora
  Logger.log(valor[1]); // Minuto
}
```

#### Otro ejemplo

La siguiente función toma el dato de la celda activa y si este es posterior a 7:05 escribe en la derecha `Sí`, y en caso contrario `No`. Se usa getDisplayValue y y el método match del objecto tipo String con la expresión regular `/\d\d/g`  para extraer la hora y minuto.

```
function estaRetrasado() {
  var celdaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var destino = celdaActiva.offset(0, 1); 
  var horaSalida = celdaActiva.getDisplayValue();
  var hms = horaSalida.match(/\d\d/g); 
  var hora = 7;
  var minuto = 5;
  var resultado = (
    (hms[0] == hora && hms[1] > minuto) ||
    (hms[0] > hora)
  )?'Sí':'No';
  destino.setValue(resultado);
}
```