# Comparar horas de Hoja de Cálculo de Google con Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una duda sobre la comparación de fechas con Google-App-Script. El script hace referencia a una Hoja de Google Sheets con la siguiente estructura:

```
|Nombre| |Asignatura| |Hora de Entrada| |Hora de Salida|  |Cansado|

 Nombre1     Bio          13:00:00          16:00:00
 Nombre1     Mate         10:00:00          14:00:00
```

La idea es que quiero comparar horas con la finalidad de agregar una etiqueta de "`si`" o "`no`" en base a la comparación. La comparación sería:  Si hora de salida > 14:30:00 escribe "`si`" en Cansado, de lo contrario escribe `no`.

El código escrito:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Probando');
if(file.hasNext()){
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.open(file.next());
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = dataRange.getValues();

    for(var i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
        var date_Breack = "14:30:00";
        if(values[i][3]>date_Breack){
            sheet.getRange(i+1, 4).setValue("Si");
        }
    }
```

El problema es que no me devuelve nada.

Alguien tiene alguna idea?

---

En relación a [Cómo leer valores de hora correctamente en una hoja de cálculo de Google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/780/c%c3%b3mo-leer-valores-de-hora-correctamente-en-una-hoja-de-c%c3%a1lculo-de-google) señalado como posible duplicado, no entiendo el motivo por el cual las entradas de la columna de End tiene la siguiente forma al hacer Logger.log de la columna de los Start:

```
[18-12-19 09:57:16:595 CET] Sat Dec 30 09:04:00 GMT+00:09 1899
```

Por dos motivos:

- El Start se introduce de la siguiente forma: `var end =
  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Europe/Berlin", "HH:mm:ss");`  Y en
  la hoja de cálculo aparece como una hora normal, sin fecha alguna,
  sólo la hora.
- Tampoco entiendo el motivo por el que aparece `09:04:00` cuando en la hoja de cálculo aparece `09:54:00`.

Los enlaces los enlaces mencionados en el posible duplicado me parecen útiles, sin embargo creo que el problema reside precisamente en que se interpreta como `[18-12-19 09:57:16:595 CET] Sat Dec 30 09:04:00 GMT+00:09 1899`. Si se interpretase como una entrada de la siguiente forma `09:54:00` creo que si se podría hacer una forma mas simple la comparación.

Comment: @Rene Recuerda eliminar los saludos

Comment: He agregado otra respuesta al enlace indicado en mi comentario previo -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/224635/65