# Problema con el formato hora al pasar los datos de spreadsheet a html

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Hago una consulta a una página de Google Sheets a través de Google Apps Scripts. Los datos llegan al cliente de forma correcta, están en formato hora. Al hacer la captura de los datos, en la hoja de cálculo están en formato `hh:mm:ss` pero al capturarlos con GAS se pasan a formato completo `Sat Dec 30 01:24:05 GMT+00:09 1899`. Por algún motivo se adelanta 24 minutos con la hora que aparece  en la celda. Por ejemplo, en la celda aparece 01:00:00 y al capturarlos `Sat Dec 30 01:24:05 GMT+00:09 1899`.

Pero la verdadera cuestión es que al intentar pasarlos a un html, no me los vuelca  en un input, mi idea es dejarlos en un `type ="time"` pero ni siquiera lo coge en un `type ="text"`.

¿Cómo puedo cambiarle el formato para que lo lea en `type ="time"?

Mi html:

```html
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="UserName" disabled style="text-align:center"></input>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" id="UserEmail" disabled style="text-align:center"></input>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" id="UserEstado" disabled style="text-align:center"></input>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" id="UserLink" disabled size="50"></input>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Entrada 1</th>
  <td><input type="time" id="E1_Lunes_Consulta"></input>
  </td>
</tr>
```

mi js

```
function buscarEmail() {
  var EmailParaBuscar = document.getElementById("EmailParaBuscar").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(llamadaDeVuelta).buscarPorEmailTrabajador(EmailParaBuscar);
}

    function llamadaDeVuelta(trabajadorEncontrado) {
  document.getElementById("UserName").value=trabajadorEncontrado[0];
  document.getElementById("UserEmail").value=trabajadorEncontrado[1];
  document.getElementById("UserEstado").value=trabajadorEncontrado[2];
  document.getElementById("UserLink").value=trabajadorEncontrado[3];
  document.getElementById("E1_Lunes_Consulta").value=trabajadorEncontrado[4];
  
}
```

Mi gs

```js
for (var i = 0; i < hojaListado.getLastRow(); i++) {
  var filaDeInfo = datos[i];
  var Nombre = filaDeInfo[1];
  var NumFila = filaDeInfo[2];
  var Estado = filaDeInfo[5];
  var Email = filaDeInfo[7];
  var Link = filaDeInfo[13];
  var L_E1 = filaDeInfo[19];


  if (Email == EmailParaBuscar) {

    //  var L_E1H = L_E1.getHours();
    //  var L_E1M = L_E1.getMinutes()-24;
    //  L_E1_1=L_E1H+":"+L_E1M;
    var trabajadorEncontrado = [Nombre, Email, Estado, Link, L_E1];
    Logger.log(trabajadorEncontrado)
  }
```

Comment: Por favor agrega un [mcve]. En el caso de las hojas de cálculo de Google esto debería incluir ejemplos de los datos que están siendo leídos de tal forma que sea claro cual el valor guardado en la celda y cuando sea relevante también el valor mostrado. También te sugiero reducir el enfoque de la pregunta, quizás primero a entender cómo se pasan los valores de la hoja de cálculo a Google Apps Script/JavaScript y quizás luego en una segunda pregunta cómo se pasan los valores de tipo fecha de JavaScript a HTML.

Comment: Hola, Rubén, te agradezco la respuesta.  El texto que hay en cada celda es 9:00:00 o  14:00:00 y también he probado con 9:00. pero en el logger.log coge los datos Sat Dec 30 09:00:00 GMT+00:09 1899. Claro, esto no me permite mostrarlo en el html.

Comment: Hola Pablo. La repuesta breve es que la hoja de cálculo de Google maneja las horas y duraciones como números seriales de la misma forma que lo hace con las fechas. Lo que estás viendo en el logger/consola es el resultado de toString() del objeto tipo Date que pasa la hoja de cálculo de Google a Google Apps Script / JavaScript.

Comment: [Posible duplicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/780/65)

Answer (score 0):

La repuesta breve es que la hoja de cálculo de Google maneja las horas y duraciones como números seriales de la misma forma que lo hace con las fechas. Lo que estás viendo en el logger/consola es el resultado de `toString()` del objeto tipo `Date` que pasa la hoja de cálculo de Google a Google Apps Script / JavaScript.

Preguntas Relacionadas

- [Cómo leer valores de hora correctamente en una hoja de cálculo de Google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/780/65)

Answer (score -1):

archivo de manifiesto "appsscript.json"

```
 "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"
```

mas tipos de timeZone
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html